# cannot square root of the result of a calculation or it is only calculating the first number in a term

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm programming a calculator and I've implemented the ability to square roots. This tool is applicable to single numbers, but it's not usable when I want to assign this tool to a number that is in an equation or the result of a calculation like 9+6 without pressing the equal key. For example, if I calculate 9+6 without pressing the equals sign and I want to take the square root of the result of 9+6, my calculator just takes the square root of nine instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
function appendOperation(operation) {
    document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML +=operation;
};

function calculateResult() {
    let container = document.getElementById('resultArea');
    let result = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML = eval(result);
};

function deleteLast() {
let container = document.getElementById('resultArea');
if(container.innerHTML.endsWith(' ')) {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.slice(0, -3);
    } 
    else {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
        }
};

function deleteContent() {
  document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = "";
};

function Percent() {
 document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML / 100;

  
  
};
 
function changingPresing() {
  
        document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML* (-1) )
};


function squared() {
    let x = document.getElementById('resultArea')
    x.innerHTML = Math.pow(parseFloat(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML), 2); // 
};      

/*This is the considered function. I did not use Math.sqrt() because it was not working.*/
function squareRoot() {
  document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.pow(parseFloat(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML)
                                                            , 0.5);
};


function faculty() {
    let repetitions = 1;
    let increasment = 1;
    let input = document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML
    while(repetitions <= input) {
      
      increasment = increasment * repetitions;
      repetitions++;
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = increasment
    } ;
};

function anyExponent() {
   exponent = prompt("Nennen Sie den Exponenten");
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.pow(parseFloat(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML),exponent );
};

function eulerscheZahl() {
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.exp(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML);
};

function Pi() {
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.PI
}

    </script>
</head>

<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

td {
  font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}

td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.operation-button {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(10, 146, 187);
}

.operation-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(6, 174, 225);
}

.changing-button {
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    color: white;
}

.changing-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(96, 93, 93);
}

.numbers:hover {
background-color: rgb(14, 13, 13);
}

#resultArea {
    height: 30vh;
    color: white;
    font-size: 64px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    
}
#resultarea:hover {
    color: #0a92bb;
}

#brackets {
width: 25%;
}







</style>


<body>

    <div id="resultArea"></div>

    <table>
        <tr>

            <td onclick="changingPresign()" class="changing-button">±</td>
            <td onclick="Percent()" class="changing-button">%</td>
            <td onclick="squared()" class="changing-button">x²</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(' / ')" class="operation-button">÷</td>
            <td id="brackets" onclick="appendOperation('(')" class="changing-button">(</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(')')" class="changing-button">)</td>



        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(7)" class="numbers">7</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(8)" class="numbers">8</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(9)" class="numbers">9</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('*')" class="operation-button">×</td>
            <td onclick="rooting()" class="changing-button">√</td>
            <td onclick="eulerscheZahl()" class="changing-button">e</td> 

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(4)" class="numbers">4</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(5)" class="numbers">5</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(6)" class="numbers">6</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('-')" class="operation-button">-</td>
            <td onclick="faculty()" class="changing-button">x!</td>
            <td onclick="anyExponent()" class="changing-button">xʸ</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(1)" class="numbers">1</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(2)" class="numbers">2</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(3)" class="numbers">3</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('+')" class="operation-button">+</td>
            <td onclick="deleteContent()" class="changing-button">AC</td>
            <td onclick="Pi()" class="changing-button">π</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(0)" colspan="2" class="numbers">0</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('.')" class="numbers">,</td>
            <td onclick="calculateResult()" id="result" class="operation-button">=</td>
            <td onclick="deleteLast()" id="ac" class="changing-button">CE</td>
            <td onclick="Ans()" class = "changing-button">Ans</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add a function to auto calc the previous variables as soon as one button is pressed and only then continue with the actual task. Also, as side note: Don't use the `onclick`-attribute but use an `eventListener` and instead of using `innerHTML` which can possess a security risk (XSS Injection) you should use `textContent`

Comment: thank you! should I always code with abstain from those methods you listed?

Comment: yes and no. Depends on the task and what you do. XSS (Cross Site Scripting) basically works by inserting a `script` tag inside input and letting the script run on another site. To counter that, you need to sanitize the input or you sue a function that does not render tags such as script (`textContent`). Also `textContent` does not need to prepare the DOM and as such is way faster than `innerhTML`. `eventListener` vs `onclick` is about the same principle as `external CSS` vs `inline-style). Its easier to maintain and to change. Keeps your HTML code clean and requires less cross checking.